# Part of this prime number program is just not making sense to me

Tags: python

Could someone explain

```
for k in range(2, 1+int(sqrt(i+1))):
```

to me? I am having a hard time comprehending how

```
1+int(sqrt(i+1)
```

truly works.

I understand `1` is being added to `i`, and it is being square rooted, and it must be an integer. But I don't comprehend how that achieves the goal of the whole program

```
from math import sqrt

count = 1
i = 1
while count < 1000:
    i += 2
    for k in range(2, 1+int(sqrt(i+1))):
        if i%k == 0:       
            break
    else:
        # print(i) ,
        count += 1
        # if count%20==0: print ""
print i
```

whose goal is to find the 1000th prime.

Comment: For any given composite number, n, we can show that at least one of its prime factors must be less than or equal to √n.  (I don't know of name for this well known fact, but it's almost trivial to prove since any prime factor greater than sqrt(n) must have a corresponding factor which is smaller or equal to it).

So this naïve method is simply implemented the algorithm described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division

Also note that the "else" close on a Python loop is for cases, like this, where a search is being performed. Search for factor or increment the count.

Answer (score 6):

If a number is to be tested for primality, it is sufficient to test all factors up to sqrt(number), because any factor above sqrt(number) has a corresponding factor below sqrt(number).

e.g. if you want to test if 36 is prime, it is sufficient to test up to 6 - for example, 12 is a factor of 36, but its other factor is 3, which you already tested by then.